# How to get nth element of a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to select the "RSI" from the first element only.

Array (json file):

```
{
"Technical": {
    "2019-01-11 15:30": {
        "RSI": "123"
    },
    "2019-01-11 14:30": {
        "RSI": "456"
    }
    "2019-01-11 14:30": {
        "RSI": "789"
    }
}
```

My php:

```
foreach ($json['Technical'] as $field => $value) {
 echo $value['RSI']; // Gives 123456789
}
```

**I want only 123**

I tried:

```
 echo $value[0]['RSI']; // Gives NULL
```

Comment: why don't you echo `$field` and `$value` in your loop to find out how you should reference the data you need?

Comment: Sûr, var_dump gives me : array(1) { ["RSI"]=> string(7) "123" } array(1) { ["RSI"]=> string(7) "456" } array(1) { ["RSI"]=> string(7) "49789" } but I don't know what to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the loop with `break;` and it will only return the first item.

```
foreach ($json['Technical'] as $field => $value) {
 echo $value['RSI']; // Gives 123
 break;
}
```

---

If you want specific items then use a "$key" variable.

```
$key = 0;
foreach ($json['Technical'] as $field => $value) {
    if($key == 0 || $key ==1){  
        echo $value['RSI']; 
    }
    $key++;
}
//  123456
```

Change the if to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Nevertheless, I said first element, but if I want the second for example, is it hard to proceed?

Comment: if you want it more dynamic - you could implement a variable, to uphold the `key` to - like `$key=0; $toFind = 1;` -- where `$toFind` is dynamic -- used by `if($key == $toFind)`

Comment: Thank you! Why the second condition for $key?

Comment: the second condition, is to get the second RSI

Comment: Yes. As @Stender says. You wanted the second item. Also it shows how to continue the code if you like. Say output 0,1 and 5.

Comment: Great thank you. Is there a way to echo outside the loop this value?